# php script hangs and doesn't exit while debugging a PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-studio

I've run into this problem twice, and didn't find an exact answer so I thought I'd post the solution I found here.

When debugging a PHPUnit test using Zend Studio the environment just hangs and doesn't exit.  When I press the stop button, the following message is displayed:

"No test was executed.  Either a fatal error occurred, the launch was stopped manually or the script execution was halted with a 'die'/'exit' statement"

The message is generic and didn't help at all.

After some research, I found a mistake in the path of a PHP file included in the unit test.  In my mind if Zend Studio encountered an invalid path, it would display a more useful message.  But alas, no.

Making the following correction resolved my issue.

From this:

```
require_once '../lib/swift_required.php';
```

To this:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
```

Comment: Maybe consider deleting this post. No use keeping this around, Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @crafter  Thanks for the welcome.  :-)  The only reason I posted it is because I was looking for an answer like this, but didn't find one.  I know it's something very few people may run into.  But, I figure if it helps a few people it's all good.